# PID for Geronimo

Tags: java, geronimo

We are trying to figure out the CPU utilization of the Geronimo instance in which the application is running.

In which file can i track to get the PID for geronimo instance.

I'm using version 2.17 of Geronimo.

Answer (score 1):

Do this in a terminal

```
$ ps aux | grep geronimo
```